# I need an AndroMan to solve the issue of Conversion to Dalvik format failed when using Lcom/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

Hi I am new to phonegap/cordova development, i try to implement `push notifications` using `Google Cloud Services` in my application.
 When i try to run my simple app i got this error :

```
  Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService;
```

and notice that there is a red mark on my project folder in the `project explorator` of `eclipse` .
i have added `GCM` with `SDK` and adding `gcm.jar` to my `libs/` folder. also i use `Google API level 17` to my project and for the `emulator` configuration.
i followed this [tuto](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/). using Google API is Recommended in this tuto but when i change it to the simple Android Api the red mark disappears

**do you have any idea about this kind of problems !?**

Comment: In your Android SDK Manger have you intalled Google Play Services and Google Cloud Messaging for Android Libarary

Comment: yes i did ! i have installed all this services

Comment: ok juste can you mention which code u need ! the MainActivity or the PushNotification.java or www files ! cuz i don't think that the problem comes from the code